# Handling Popup with Togglebutton

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, wpf-controls

I have a Toggle button and a popup in Xaml. popup's IsOpen bound to toggle button's IsChecked and the Popup's StaysOpen is set to false. So the popup will get open when the toggle button checked and close if unchecked. This works fine.

My problem is i have opened the popup and click away from popup, this close my popup due to its stays open false and if i tried to open the popup by clicking the toggle button, popup not get open. Since it is in checked state, and its turn into unchecked state. so its not open the popup.

Any idea, How may i handle this?

Comment: I'd try to make it a two-way-binding, so that when the popup closes the togglebutton gets unchecked

Comment: @SebastianEdelmeier: Yes, the Binding mode is in TwoWay but the IsOpen will not change when it closes.

Answer (score 4):

Set StaysOpen = "True" or even better StaysOpen="{Binding ElementName=TogglePopupButton,Path=IsMouseOver}".

With the second approach you get 2 benefits.
1) The PopUp closes if the user clicks outside the popUpview.
The PopUp Closes if you click on the ToggleButton again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this is an old thread, nevertheless it helped me to find a working solution. The problem was, that closing the popup by pressing the toggle button immediately reopened the popup, even checking the `IsMouseOver` state did not always prevent this. Here is what worked for me:

```
<ToggleButton
    x:Name="popToolboxTreeToggle"
    IsHitTestVisible="{Binding ElementName=popToolboxTree, Path=IsOpen, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}" />
<Popup
    x:Name="popToolboxTree"
    IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=popToolboxTreeToggle, Path=IsChecked}"
    StaysOpen="false"
    PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=popToolboxTreeToggle}">
    <TreeView />
</Popup>
```

By disabling the hittest, the button does not react as long as the popup is open and therefore the mouse click is handled the same way as an outside click would do. It requires to add an `InverseBooleanConverter` to the resource dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Handle popups Closed/Opened events and on there toggle CheckBox states, and vice versa. I've had similiar problems myself with Popup.